# Why concurrentmodificationexception when print a set with System.out.println()?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification, system.out

I am reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), according to some java code in it, `System.out.println()` will  led to `ConcurrentModificationException`. The code is below :

```
private final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

public synchronized void add(Integer i) {set.add(i); }

public synchronized void remove(Integer i) {set.remove(i);}

public void addTenThings() {

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        add(r.nextInt());
    }

    System.out.println("DEBUG: add ten elements to " + set );
}
```

Since the `System.out.println()` method will just call the `toString` method:

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
if (! i.hasNext())
    return "[]";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append('[');
for (;;) {
    E e = i.next();
    sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
    if (! i.hasNext())
    return sb.append(']').toString();
    sb.append(", ");
}
}
```

I still can not understand why `ConcurrentModificationException` be throw??

Comment: You are iterating over the collection while another thread could be modifying it.  Your `" + set` calls toString() on the `set` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 2 threads - `A` and `B` executing the method `addTenThings()` at the same time. They can do it, as the method isn't synchronized.

Then if during the time the thread `A` is executing `toString()` method of `set`, thus iterating over it, the thread `B` is still executing the loop, and invokes the `add()` method, that might cause `ConcurrentModificationException`, as both the threads are operating on the same `set` only. Nothing stops a thread to execute the `add(r.nextInt())` statement, while a different thread is executing the `print` statement in the method.

Comment: I did this for server times as you said, but nothing happened, did I miss something?

Comment: @znlyj You could do it a billion times and not see this bug on one machine but when you ran it on a different machine, JVM version or OS you might see it all the time.  10 things is very small so one thread can run to completion before the other one starts.

Comment: Got it. Both **add** and **remove** method might throw the exception when these modify operation and iterate happened at the same time.